# Why am I getting a dimensional error when I use a 2-dim convolutional input layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a Keras deep learning question:

I'm building a mnist classifier, but the input layer of my neural network is a 2nd Dimensional Convolutional layer. The training set has 60000 samples, and the testing set has 10000 samples. The dimensions of each image is 28 by 28 pixels. I take the pixel tensor slices and squash it down to a two parameter tensor, divide by 255, and make it a 'float32'.

imports:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, MaxPooling2D, Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.datasets import mnist
```

Loading the Data:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
```

Pre-processing:

```
train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') /255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') /255
```

Then I run it through a 2-Dim Convolutional Input Layer:

```
network = Sequential()
network.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='valid', data_format="channels_last", input_shape = (60000, 784)))
```

Full Model:

```
network = Sequential()
network.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='valid', data_format="channels_last", input_shape = (60000, 784)))
network.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format="channels_last"))
network.add(Conv2D(64, (2,2), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid',  data_format=None, dilation_rate=(1, 1), activation=None, use_bias=True, 
kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', 
kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, 
kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None))
network.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid', data_format=None))
network.add(Flatten())
network.add(Dense(128, activation= 'relu'))
network.add(Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=7))
network.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_7: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3
```

So I tried to add a channel dimension (to represent black white):

```
network = Sequential()
network.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding='valid', 
data_format="channels_last", input_shape = (60000, 784, 1)))
```

I still get an error when I try to fit the data, but this time my model compiles

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_3_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 784)
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to make sure that Conv2d takes the input shape as `( height , width , number of channels )` Also a batch size dimension has to be added at the beginning. The whole dimension becomes `( batch size , height , width , number of channels )`.

- Your input shape is `( 60000 , 784 , 1 )`
  Here 60000 is your **batch size** and the number of channels is 1.
- For the Conv2d , you input shape should be `( 28 , 28 ,1 )`. You **do not need to mention the batch size for Conv2d**.